# flickering div on hover firefox

Tags: jquery, css

How do I stop flickering of this div when it's hovered, it is only having issue in firefox, chrome is fine

http://jsfiddle.net/GpuUb/

jQuery solutions are fine

CSS

```
div {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
}

div:hover {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much flickering as it is losing the hover event. Firefox does not detect your mouse in the whitespace portion of the `border-radius` as a hover. If you move your mouse such that it stays in the black portion, it smoothly transitions.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in Firefox, the other browsers, or it's undefined by the spec. From what I've read in the CSS3 specification, there's no discussion about how `border-radius` might affect the box model. Perhaps by that omission, it shouldn't affect the box model and then this would be a defect in Firefox.

You can fix it with a wrapped container div, but that's not terribly elegant. Here's a modified version of yours with the wrapper div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"><div id="circle"></div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#container {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 50px;
}
div#circle {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
}

div#container:hover div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpuUb/1/) to play with.

Answer (score 1):

I would Position the circle in the middle of the and expand it equally to all sides. Then the flicker effect doesn't occur:

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 75px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
}

div:hover {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 00px;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/eNabK/

I don't know applicatiable this is for you.